# Dell Vostro 15 3549 just won’t boot into Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: boot, uefi, ssd

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS onto the laptop using a USB stick. When I use the try Ubuntu option I can see the laptop’s SSD, with all of the Ubuntu files in it. However, when I try and boot from the SSD with Ubuntu on it, the laptop can’t see the boot device and thinks there’s nothing to boot from. I have tried reinstalling a couple of times, removing and reseating the SSD, and I have tried with and without Secure boot. I have also tried using boot-repair from within the try Ubuntu area and that said it had repaired the installation but nothing changed in terms of the booting. I’ve also tried updating the bios of the laptop to the latest version and that didn’t help either.

Output of the boot-info generator before I ran the repair - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h8CvVrzfjb/
Output of boot-info after i ran the repair - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DYKDtxtXvg/

[having done some more troubleshooting this seems to be a BIOS issue with the laptop's BIOS not recognising certain storage devices. However, if anyone knows how to fix this I would be grateful :-)]

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using, as this will help in the troubleshooting process. Thanks